# WHILE loop math logic

Tags: sql, oracle, while-loop

```
DECLARE
totalSpendAmt NUMBER(6,2) := 100;
itemPrice NUMBER(6,2) := 129.99;
qty NUMBER(6,2) :=1;
BEGIN
WHILE 
totalspendamt >= itemprice LOOP 
totalspendamt := totalspendamt - itemprice; 
qty := qty + 1; 
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total quantity can be purchased '||qty);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total amount spend '||qty * itemprice);
END;
```

The above code calculates the total quantity of a specified item that can be purchased with a given amount of money. I keep getting "Total quantity can be purchased 1. Total amount spend 129.99" The answer should be 0. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a requirement to use a WHILE LOOP?  The reason I ask, is this is not normally the type of problem to be solved with a while loop.

Comment: Yes it is a requirement, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looping while totalspendamt >= itemprice, but that isn't true when the while loop begins so the loop won't ever run. 100 < 129.99.

Also, you should realize that what you're doing is division. You're counting the number of times one number fits into another. Dividing instead of looping will give you much better performance.

Some style comments: you'll probably want to use camelCase or under_score variable names for readability. I have a hard time reading your variable names as is.

Comment: Thank you, I understand where my error is. My loop is not running. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Well you probably want to start the quantity you can purchase at 0 instead of one. Then you'll get zero for both values you're printing.

Comment: well the problem is that i have a table where the qty is 1, so it can not be changed

Comment: Well, reduce it to zero or by one? I mean, set up your table how you like, but with this algoritm starting at zero is what makes sense. You could write a new Algorithm that used 1 instead of zero to mean zero but at that point it's kind of silly.